# Python smtp (Postfix MTA) mailing: Get notified when recipient open sent mail

Tags: python, email

I'm building a Python **3.7** script to automatically send around 700 e-mails through my company's SMTP server. All the sending is working fine, but I need to be warned about which recipients opened the mail, so I can highlight them as valid in my list. Can anyone with experience on this matter explain how it works?

Although there are some questions regarding the header option "Disposition-Notification-To", none of it really explains how this works.

1. Whose responsibility is it to prompt the reader to confirm reading the message?
2. Whose responsibility is to send an e-mail back to my address in case the reader confirms the prompt?
3. Are there other options to reach this goal?

Since every question on this was low on info and/or used older Python versions, I intend, with this question, to gather dependable and updated info source on this matter.

```py
def build_message(address):
    mail = EmailMessage()

    mail['From'] = MY_EMAIL
    mail['To'] = address
    mail['Subject'] = "This is a TEST"
    mail['Disposition-Notification-To'] = MY_EMAIL
    mail.set_content('Hello this is a test')

    image_cid = make_msgid(domain='xyz.com')
    mail.add_alternative("""\
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <p>This is a test.</p>
                        <img src="cid:{image_cid}">
                    </body>
                </html>
                """.format(image_cid=image_cid[1:-1]), subtype='html')

    with io.open(attachment_path, 'rb') as img:
        maintype, subtype = mimetypes.guess_type(img.name)[0].split('/')
        mail.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(),
                                          maintype=maintype,
                                          subtype=subtype,
                                          cid=image_cid)

    return mail
```

This is my message building function and the result is sent via SMTP opened session (smtplib). Although "Disposition-Notification-To" header is placed, nothing different happens.

EDIT: My company's mail UI offers the "Notify read" option, so I know my credentials are allowed to do it (GMAIL standard accounts won't allow reading notification).

EDIT 2: My company uses Postfix as MTA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your company's smtp providers should provide an API from which you can get the delivery status reports on every sent email.

From my own experience,
In our company, we use sendgrid's smtp server for sending mails, sendgrid provides us with an API for reading status reports of every sent email once the delivery status report is enabled from settings. These reports are being remotely posted in web page which you supplied in the settings. These reports are posted in json format, you can get information if the user opened the email or if the email went to the spam folder from this reports.

So, I think you should also ask your SMTP providers how you can go about this with their service.

Comment: I now understand that it's up to the SMTP's MTA to support DSN (Delivery Status Notifications). I've also checked that my company's MTA is the open source Postfix and it supports DSN (info added to question). According to Postfix' s [DSN support docs](http://www.postfix.org/DSN_README.html), I should be able to get the following notifications: success, failure or delay, being the last two always informed by default. I'll try to make this work and will edit this comment in case I do. Meanwhile any Postfix experts are welcome to share knowledge.

Comment: Added `s.send_message(mail, rcpt_options=['NOTIFY=SUCCESS,DELAY,FAILURE'])` to the Python's smptlib send command and got the following reply: `>send: 'rcpt TO:<destinymail@gmail.com> NOTIFY=SUCCESS,DELAY,FAILURE' >reply: b'501 5.7.1 DSN support is disabled'.` "DSN support is disabled" means it's disabled in my MTA? It means it's disabled in my destiny's MTA? Or even it meas it's disabled in one of it (I heard DSN must be supported by both sender and recipient, otherwise it doesn't work)?

Comment: Apparently, there are two ways a `SMTP` can know what happened to a sent mail. Through `DSN` (Delivery Status Notification) and `MDN` (Message Delivery Notification). `DSN` is a `SMTP` service and it's very reliable, but it must be set and active among `SMTP`'s `EHLO` reply services. It can be requested by adding `NOTIFY=SUCCESS,DELAY,FAILURE` to recipient options (`rcpt_options`) while sending a mail. `MDN` is a convention in mail systems which states a few magic headers that will be understood by the mail system and will prompt the user for letting the sender know the user opened the mail.

Comment: `DSN` is obviously newer and actually reliable. It must be activated in both sides (sender and recipient) to work. Most public mail providers (such as Gmail) set it off for regular users, offering the feature for business and school accounts. `MDN` on the other hand is supported by default, unless turned off by the mail admin. Gmail blocks this as well and will ignore the header. As I had `DSN` off in my `SMTP`, I used the `MDN` header `Disposition-Notification-To=sendermail@senderdomain.com` and it works with smaller mail systems recipients (such as Postfix users) but doesn't with Gmail.